# Oktava or Audio-Technica for Omni Ambience Recording?

Tags: ambience, omni, self-noise

I´m getting a rig to record quiet ambience with a Jecklin disc or simply using a spaced technique and would like to know if anyone has experience comparing the Audio-Technica AT4022 and the Oktava MK012 MSP6 with the omni capsules. Mostly concerned about self-noise here. Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2):

Oktava MK012 have a reputation for being not as quiet as most similar microphones. Both the electrical self-noise and the mechanical handling noise are weak spots in the Oktava's reputation.  If I had to choose, I would think that the AT4022 would very likely be quieter than the Oktava MK012.  I own a pair of Oktava MK012 and I would think twice about using them in a low-level sound application.

Answer (score 1):

I like my AT4022s a lot and I prefer them to the Oktavas (which I've used a few times). Folks who own the Oktavas tend to enthuse about them, but I like many of the AT 40 series of microphones.

Answer (score 1):

No direct experience with the Oktavas, but the 4022s are really good mics and have a great reputation with nature sound recordists. There is also evidence of them testing quieter than the spec from Audio Technica here:

https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/type/www/audio-reports/MicSpecCharts/Mics_16dBA.htm